# Cache already exists error with CFCACHE

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfcache

I've recently used CFCACHE to implement page caching on a cold fusion 9 server.

However I'm getting errors reported under load (running an automated link checker) like:
"Cache A95C0BF9E9BFBC6F151F03E939D2D2D6TEMPLATE already exists"

I had thought that cfcache would be thread safe, and handle this without any extra code. If it is relevant I'm calling it within "OnRequest" within my application.cfc. To me it seems like perhaps this is a Cold Fusion bug, but it's also possible I'm abusing the CFCACHE mechanism in some way.

```
<!--- setup caching if enabled --->
<cfif getConfigValue('page_cache') eq "true" and not application.security.isLoggedOn()>
    <cfcache timespan="#createTimeSpan(0,0,10,0)#" directory="#application.pagecachepath#" usequerystring="true" >
</cfif>
<!--- Call request handling and rendering functions --->
<cfcontent reset="yes" type="text/html"><cfoutput>#html.render()#</cfoutput>
<cfif getConfigValue('page_cache') eq "true" and not application.security.isLoggedOn()><!-- content generated at #Now()#--></cfif>
```

The stack trace is:

```
    net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache A95C0BF9E9BFBC6F151F03E939D2D2D6TEMPLATE already exists at 
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:920) at 
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:915) at 
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:870) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.ehcache.GenericEhcache.createCache(GenericEhcache.java:317) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.ehcache.GenericEhcache._getCache(GenericEhcache.java:301) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.ehcache.GenericEhcache.getCache(GenericEhcache.java:268) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.ehcache.GenericEhcache.get(GenericEhcache.java:72) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.CacheTagHelper.checkFromTemplateCache(CacheTagHelper.java:56) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.CacheTag.checkTemplatecache(CacheTag.java:695) at 
    coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.CacheTag.doStartTag(CacheTag.java:609) at 
    coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722) at cfapplication2ecfc814216694$funcONREQUEST._factor1(C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.org\httpdocs\application.cfc:190) at 
    cfapplication2ecfc814216694$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.org\httpdocs\application.cfc:187) at 
    coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at 
    coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405) at  
    coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at
```

Absent any better ideas I guess I'll start looking into the EH cache source!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

race condition in coldfusion.tagext.io.cache.ehcache.GenericEhcache

Looks like it exists in both CF9 & 10 (based on source code)

your only solution is to put cflock somewhere to fix this yourself.